# How Do I Confine The Pagewidth

Tags: html, css, scroll, width, overflow

The width of my page is too wide, so that you can scroll to the right and it will pass all the page elements. Here's a screenshot: [image: screenshot]

- The black part is the footer, as you can see, you can scroll right past it.

I have used `overflow-x: none;` to prevent horizontal scolling, however you can still scroll this way by holding down the middle mouse button and scrolling.

How can I confine my pagewidth? Setting it to 100% will make it native to the screen's resolution; however for some reason it has gone past that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a live jsfiddle/codepen example demonstrating your problem. You'll probably need to set correct width/overflow/box-sizing to all element's parents.

Comment: I would, however I am not sure what the actual problem is that is causing this. I need some code to confine the pagewidth

Comment: If you create a live demonstration, we can actually see, which code is causing the problem. It's hard to debug a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you right, you should be able to do this in your css:

```
body {
  width: /*the width you want*/;  
}
```

I maybe understood you wrong or maybe I didn't!

Edit:
Try adding this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: The problem with that, is that it isn't responsive. I've set my width to 100% so that it will be correct on all devices